# Merge MySQL Query as a nested query

Tags: mysql

I have written 3 queries in MySQL and all 3 are working perfectly but I want to merge them all

here is 1st query:

```
SELECT  d.ContactId
     , d.ContactAddress
     , d.Channel
     , d.InitiationTimestamp
     , d.InitiationMethod
     , d.RecordingID
     , d.ConnectedToAgentTimestamp
     , d.AgentInteractionDuration
     , d.QueueName
     , d.NextContactId
     , d.PreviousContactId
     , d.WrapUpData
     , d.Tag
     , u.FirstName
     , u.LastName
     , f.Score
     , r.Location
  FROM CallDetail d
  Left
  join UserTable u
    On d.UserID = u.UserID 
  left 
  join Feedback f
    on d.ContactAddress = f.FeedbackID 
  left 
  join Recordings r
    on d.RecordingID = r.RecordingID
 where d.ContactAddress = '+443300883940' 
 order 
    by d.InitiationTimestamp
```

Result of 1st Query

[image]

2nd query

```
select TagId
, Name
from Tag, CallDetail
where CallDetail.ContactAddress = '+443300883940' and LOCATE(Tag.TagId, CallDetail.Tag) > '0';
```

Result of 2nd Query

[image]

3rd query

```
select WrapupId
, Name
from WrapupCodes, CallDetail
where CallDetail.ContactAddress = '+443300883940' and LOCATE(WrapupCodes.WrapupId, CallDetail.WrapUpData) > '0';
```

Result of 3rd Query

[image]

How I can merge them all and use as a nested query?

Comment: Can you provide sample expected output ?

Comment: probably table structure as well. what fields in what table

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes as you can see in the first query calldetail.ConatactId is in CallDetail's Table and so on

Comment: how can i provide expected output there are 4 to 5 tables and too many fields

Comment: If you don't show us a proper data sample and the expected  resutl  .. we can't imagine how join / merge / nesting  your code  ..

Comment: LOCATE() implies a lack of normalisation. I would attend to that first.

Comment: @Strawberry didn't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: @scaisEdge I have updated my question. I added the picture of the result of each query you can check now, see if it is helpful for your guyz

Comment: @Jfrd I have updated my question. I added the picture of the result of each query you can check now, see if it is helpful for your guyz

Comment: @Tayyab can put the data what you are expecting after 'merge', hard to understand your expectation here, for me.